# Improve PostgreSQL set difference efficiency

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql

I'm trying to do some set operations in PostgreSQL 9.3.

I have two tables, for simplicity let's call them `table_a` and `table_b`:

```
create table table_a(id varchar primary key);
create table table_b(id varchar primary key);
```

And I have a simple query (in its simplest formulation, though it's a source for an insert in practice):

```
(select id from table_a) except (select id from table_b);
```

Before I started using PostgreSQL, I'd do an operation like this:

```
set-diff table_a.csv table_b.csv > table_c.csv
```

Where set-diff looks approximately like this:

```
while (not eof(a)) and (not eof(b)):
  line_a <- peek_line(a)
  line_b <- peek_line(b)
  if line_a < line_b:
    output read_line(a)
  else if line_a == line_b:
    read_line(a)
  else:
    read_line(b)
while not eof(a):
  output read_line(a)
```

This doesn't take very long at all, has insignificant memory requirements, and maximizes efficient use of sequential disk I/O. That's important since this machine doesn't have heaps of memory - it can't fit all the data in RAM.

However, PostgreSQL comes up with this kind of plan (from some actual tables):

```
                                    QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SetOp Except  (cost=3184554.28..3238904.44 rows=9434298 width=51)
   ->  Sort  (cost=3184554.28..3211729.36 rows=10870032 width=51)
         Sort Key: "*SELECT* 1".id
         ->  Append  (cost=0.00..428039.64 rows=10870032 width=51)
               ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.00..345707.96 rows=9434298 width=54)
                     ->  Seq Scan on table_a  (cost=0.00..251364.98 rows=9434298 width=54)
               ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..82331.68 rows=1435734 width=32)
                     ->  Seq Scan on table_b  (cost=0.00..67974.34 rows=1435734 width=32)
```

The query takes way too long - several minutes.

I'm convinced that PostgreSQL could use the same kind of merge strategy I outline above, using index scans alone, and no sorting. Instead it seems to be concatenating two table scans and sorting the whole lot of them, a little bit like this command line, though without reading table_b twice:

```
sort table_a.csv table_b.csv table_b.csv | uniq -u
```

This involves rather a lot of extra work - some fraction of log(n) times more I/O, for one, when not everything will fit in memory.

The columns involved are btree indexed. The only column being selected from the query is the same one that is indexed and is being merged. Locale is C everywhere.

Before I was using a lot of text files and a few custom indexing tools. I'm trying to use a database instead to get extra flexibility in querying and to avoid having to maintain custom indexes. However the performance is appalling, so much so that I'm considering doing my merges and most other mass update operations outside the database, round-tripping the data through csv.

What am I missing?

Comment: You might want to migrate this question to dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thoughts:

- Plain `EXCEPT` means `EXCEPT DISTINCT` which means it eliminates duplicate rows from its result. Use `EXCEPT ALL` if you can, it *should* be faster.
- Don't use [combining queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-union.html) if you have another options too, they are known to be slow.
- From your `EXPLAIN`, it seems you applied an ordering too, which also takes more time (especially on combining queries).

Results on my `9.2`:

**`EXCEPT`**

```
explain select id from table_a except (select id from table_b);
```

results:

```
HashSetOp Except  (cost=0.00..947.00 rows=20000 width=5)
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..872.00 rows=30000 width=5)
        ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.00..563.00 rows=20000 width=5)
              ->  Seq Scan on table_a  (cost=0.00..363.00 rows=20000 width=5)
        ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..309.00 rows=10000 width=4)
              ->  Seq Scan on table_b  (cost=0.00..209.00 rows=10000 width=4)
```

**`EXCEPT` with `ORDER BY`**

```
explain select id from table_a except (select id from table_b) order by id;
```

results:

```
Sort  (cost=2375.77..2425.77 rows=20000 width=5)
  Sort Key: "*SELECT* 1".id
  ->  HashSetOp Except  (cost=0.00..947.00 rows=20000 width=5)
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..872.00 rows=30000 width=5)
              ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.00..563.00 rows=20000 width=5)
                    ->  Seq Scan on table_a  (cost=0.00..363.00 rows=20000 width=5)
              ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..309.00 rows=10000 width=4)
                    ->  Seq Scan on table_b  (cost=0.00..209.00 rows=10000 width=4)
```

**Anti `JOIN` with `ORDER BY`**

```
explain select table_a.id from table_a
left outer join table_b on table_a.id = table_b.id
where table_b.id is null order by table_a.id;
```

and

```
explain select id from table_a
where not exists (select * from table_b where table_b.id = table_a.id) order by id;
```

results (identical):

```
Merge Anti Join  (cost=0.57..1213.57 rows=10000 width=5)
  Merge Cond: ((table_a.id)::text = (table_b.id)::text)
  ->  Index Only Scan using table_a_pkey on table_a  (cost=0.29..688.29 rows=20000 width=5)
  ->  Index Only Scan using table_b_pkey on table_b  (cost=0.29..350.29 rows=10000 width=4)
```

**`NOT IN` with `ORDER BY`**

```
explain select id from table_a where id not in (select id from table_b) order by id;
```

results (my winner):

```
Seq Scan on table_a  (cost=234.00..647.00 rows=10000 width=5)
  Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Seq Scan on table_b  (cost=0.00..209.00 rows=10000 width=4)
```

Used

```
create table table_a(id varchar primary key, rnd float default random());
create table table_b(id varchar primary key, rnd float default random());

do language plpgsql $$
begin
    for i in 1 .. 10000 loop
        insert into table_a(id) values (i);
        insert into table_b(id) values (i);
    end loop;
    for i in 10001 .. 20000 loop
        insert into table_a(id) values (i);
    end loop;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: Nice. You can add the `NOT EXISTS` version as well.

Comment: It's there, right under *Anti JOIN*, because they have identical plan.

Comment: Oops, I missed that ;)

Answer (score 1):

How do these variants do?

```
select id
from table_a a
where not exists (select 1 from table_b b where b.id = a.id);
```

or:

```
select id
from table_a left outer join
     table_b b
     on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null;
```

If these perform better, it is simply that not as much effort has going into optimizing `except` as other components of the language.

Comment: I tried both those variants last night (I found out how slow `not in` is vs `not exists` and the weird SQL standard null handling behind it), and I thought I was being a little bit cunning with the left outer join version. Both have the same plan, approximately `merge_anti_join(merge(external_sort(table_a), materialize(sort(table_b))))` but no improvement in run time.

Comment: @BarryKelly . . . That is surprising.  I thought these would make better use of the index.

Comment: Earlier I added an integer key to table_a and a unique index for it. Numbering the rows using a stored procedure and a cursor took several hours, and while a few million more rows were concurrently being inserted (so the indexed column has quite a few nulls). I mention this because direct equality lookups on integers are now using full table scans even when a unique index exists for the column. I've run analyze, vacuum etc., dropped and recreated the index but no difference. Very strange, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/15965785/3712

Comment: I should add I tried using `set enable_seqscan=false` and it still won't use the index. Something is borked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you vacuumed your tables?  What is `relallvisible` from `pg_class`?  An index scan is unfavorable if it also has to visit the tables for each row, as that is scattered IO.

With vacuumed tables, I get a merge join between two index-only scans.

I think you have an unrealistic expectation of what databases do.  You can always write your own code that will do any given operation faster than a database can, especially if you ignore ACID in the process.

For example if you keep your data sorted, then you can avoid doing sorts (provided there is only one key you ever need to sort on).  But then you can no longer do efficient updates or insertions.

Comment: I've vacuumed the tables. The column being joined is the only one selected and is indexed, so no visiting table. I don't think my expectations are too unrealistic; I expected a constant multiplier slowdown and a blowup in disk and memory usage.  I did not expect 1000x blowup in time, however, which is close to what I'm seeing in practice and is very much not what the database should be able to do with the info available to it. It seems something is broken in my postgres instance. I'm not at the db at the moment to answer your metadata question.

Comment: @BarryKelly As long as the tables are vacuumed and relallvisible is high, I get the merge join between index-only scans.  I don't know why you aren't getting them.  Can you post a script to generate dummy data that demonstrates this?  PostgreSQL does not store visibility info in the index, so it does have to visit the table unless allvisible is set for the page.  If I trick it into doing the index merge when the data is too large to fit in RAM and allvisible is not set, the performance is catastrophic.

Comment: @BarryKelly If you blow up the space, you can easily cross the boundary where the working set no longer fits in RAM.  This could certainly cause a catastrophic slow down in some cases, but I doubt you are really seeing 1000x.  I get about a 5 times slowdown when going from merge anti join of index only scans to the SetOp-Sort-Append